# how to prepare view in struts 1.x

Tags: java, model-view-controller, jsp, struts, struts-1

I'm a struts newbie. I have a `Form`, an `Action` and a `jsp view`.

```
<form-beans>
    <form-bean name="bookEventForm" type="com.example.BookEventForm" />
</form-beans>

<action path="/bookEvent"
        type="com.example.BookEventAction"
        name="bookEventForm"
        input="/WEB-INF/jsp/bookEvent.jsp"
        scope="request">
    <forward name="success" path="/WEB-INF/jsp/bookEvent.jsp" />
</action>
```

One of the properties of the event form is `Country` so the first thing I do in `Action` is:

```
request.setAttribute("countries", countriesDao.getAll());
```

in the view I render the select element using:

```
<html:select property="..." >
    <html:optionsCollection name="countries" ... />
</html:select>
```

This works fine until I add [ActionForm#validate](http://struts.apache.org/1.2.7/api/org/apache/struts/action/ActionForm.html#validate%28org.apache.struts.action.ActionMapping,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest%29) to do some validation checks (unrelated to countries, e.g surname != null).

By struts spec as soon as there is an error the `Action#execute` never executes. Thus the `countries` collection is no longer in the request and the view renders with an empty select element.

I know that I'm most probably missing some core concept of struts. A friend suggested to make the dao available on the view so I can fetch the countries any time but I generaly prefer to prepare the view (prefetch db data) before any JSP "code" is executed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did to overcome the struts `validate` issue was to bypass struts and add my own `validate` method on the `Form`:

```
public ActionErrors validate() {
    ActionErrors errors = new ActionErrors();
    if (...) errors.add("name", new ActionError("error.field.mandatory"));
    if (...) errors.add("surname", new ActionError("error.field.mandatory"));
    return errors;
}
```

And call it from the `Action`:

```
saveErrors(request, ((BookEventForm)form).validate());
```

Works great and fulfills my requirements. The action is now always executed before presenting the view, the error or the success page and has code which prepares the view.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way would be to use the prepopulation method described [here](http://struts.apache.org/1.x/faqs/newbie.html). I've never personally used this approach though (I used session scoped forms).

Alternatively, you can include the setting of the country list in the validate() method of your form (but this is a bit of a hack).

Comment: Adding the countries loading in the validate() method does work but it's a definite violation of layering and MVC.

Answer (score 0):

As far as my knowledge goes, if validate fails, the control comes back to screen with the ActionErrors populated in the validate method.  And before validate is invoked, the form is populated.

Comment: Yes but I need some Java code (preferably an action) which will run execute before control is dispatched to the JSP. I need this in order to load the countries list from the database.

Comment: In that case, I suggest you do it as a pre process to screen load and keep it in session cache.

Comment: I'm not fond of storing that kind of data in the http session. I don't think it is correct.

Comment: Well, yes, in a way you are right, keeping session as clean as possible is desirable. Another way is putting your code right in the validate method, subject to some conditions.

Comment: Puting this code in the validate method does work but feels wrong regarding layering and MVC.

Comment: Again, you are right.  But struts may not support all requirements.  In that case either a workaround is needed, or a change of framework.  Your choice.

Answer (score 0):

There actually is a mechanism built in Struts 1 that allows what you needed : the ActionForm's reset method.

It is intended to reset the form's fields to default values, but as it is executed before the population of the form, i.e. before the validate method is called, it works well to store collections or other objects in the session too :

```
@Override
public void reset(ActionMapping mapping, HttpServletRequest request) {
    request.setAttribute(SITES, siteDao.findAll());
    request.setAttribute(SERVICES, serviceDao.findAll());
}
```